# HTML5 fullscreen mode in mobile browser (chrome) ignores the viewport configuration - bug or feature?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, viewport, html5-fullscreen

My app displays some pages for a mobile device. Such pages have the `<viewport>` tag carefully calculated so that they will fit 100% in the device screen, something like:

```
<meta id="sysviewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.79, minimum-scale=0.79, maximum-scale=0.79, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

From the app, you can enter FullScreen mode via a call to the HTML5 api:

```
$(document.documentElement).fullScreen(true);
```

(the jQuery module just calls `requestFullScreen()` looking for the vendor prefix, etc..)

What happens is, when in FullScreen mode, viewport scale is ignored (reset to "1" i guess). When I exit full-screen mode the viewport scale is again honored.

Is this a bug? A gray area in the documentation? Or is the expected functionality of full screen mode? Also can anybody confirm this happens also on mobile safari?

I did some tests manually scaling the `<body>` myself when in fullscreen mode via a `zoom` or `transform`, but the performance is terrible compared to the `viewport` scaling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The values of meta viewport attribute are not reflected when in full screen mode in android chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954761/the-values-of-meta-viewport-attribute-are-not-reflected-when-in-full-screen-mode)